# Set variable counting up in while loop to different variable name using modulus

Tags: python

What I have:

```
x = 0
while x <= image_number:
        x = x + 1
        (a%d % x)  = pyfits.open("final_processed%d.fit" % x)
```

What I want:

To set variables (in this case, a1, a2, a3 etc.) = the opened images via Pyfits to numbers ranging from 1 - # of images in the directory. So basically:

```
a1 = pyfits.open("final_processed1.fit")
a2 = pyfits.open("final_processed2.fit")
a3 = pyfits.open("final_processed3.fit")
...
```

and so on for all of the images in the directory. I want to save them all under a different variable so I don't have to mess around with arrays etc.

Brandon

Comment: exec('a%d = pyfits.open("final_processed%d.fit")' % (x, x)). But I will reject code with exec for a public project.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?  Just build a dictionary, or even a list of opened files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create different variable names while in a loop? (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop-python)

Answer (score 0):

**never use exec when you can use something much safer like dictionary, it can be dangerous  and is not pythonic!**

```
d={}
for x in range(number_of_your_photos):
        d["a{0}".format(x)]=("final_processed{0}.fit".format(x))
```

then you have a dictionary of your images!

Comment: he does't want „arrays”, but named vars

Comment: He should perhaps first answer why he thinks he needs specially named local variables.