# Creating classes inside a loop Python

Tags: python, class, loops

I'm working on a Python project and I want to do something like the next example, but is incorrect. I need some help, please!

```
names = ['name1', 'name2']

for name in names:
    class name:
        [statements]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Explain what you are trying to accomplish, and in what way this is "incorrect".

Comment: Related: [How can you dynamically create variables in Python via a while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop) and [How do you create different variable names while in a loop? (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `class` statement requires a hard-coded class name. You can use the `type` function, however, to create such dynamic classes.

```
names = ['name1', 'name2']
class_dict = {}
for name in names:
    # statements to prepare d
    class_dict[name] = type(name, (object,), d)
```

Here, `d` is a dictionary that should contain any attributes and methods that you would have defined in your class. `class_dict` is used to store your `class` objects, as injecting dynamic names directly into the global namespace is a bad idea.

Here is a concrete example of using the `type` function to create a class.

```
d = {}
d['foo'] = 5
def initializer(self, x):
    self.x = x + 6
d['__init__'] = initializer
MyClass = type('MyClass', (object,), d)
```

This produces the same class as the following `class` statement.

```
class MyClass(object):
    foo = 5
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x + 6
```

Comment: As `type()` creates an object of `<type 'type'>` (not `classobj`) we can replace `(object,)`  with `()`. But yeah *Explicit is better than implicit.* :-)

Comment: Ah, true, I see a `type` instance inherits from `object` whether or not you include `object` in the base-class tuple.