# How to use different variables in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to use variables with different names while in a `for` loop.
Before I explain anything else, let me say that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop-python) is not the problem I am having.  Yes, I am creating different variables based on the index of the `for` loop, but I understand from that and other resources how to do that.

What I do not know how to do is how to call different variables within the `for` loop.  What I mean is I want something sort of like this:

```
# pre-defined variables
object_1 = 7
object_2 = 8
object_3 = 51

# create new dictionary
Things = {}

# populate dictionary
for i in range(1,4):
    Things['thing_%d'%i] = object_i
```

So I know how to create separate new variables (using the dictionary `Things`).  What I want to do is have a way that, as seen in the last line, the program identifies the variable with index `i` (`object_i`) for use in defining the element in the `Things` dictionary `thing_i`.

Is there a way to do this without having to write a separate line of code for each variable (like shown below)?

```
Things['thing_1'] = object_1
Things['thing_2'] = object_2
Things['thing_3'] = object_3
```

**UPDATED EDIT AND CLARIFICATION**: The reason I cannot use a dictionary to define `object_1`, `object_2`, and `object_3` is they are not actually defined in the Python script.  I have to call them from a Salome (3D modeling program) file where they are indexed as `Face_1`, `Face_2`, etc.  I would love to have everything in elements of an array (eliminating the need for separate variables), but in order to do that, I still need to call up the objects from Salome.  I currently have a script that I am running in the Salome Python console that starts out like this so I can access the objects from the Salome study:

```
# Salome testing
import salome
salome.salome_init("C:\Users\Me\Study3.hdf")

import GEOM
from salome.geom import geomBuilder
geompy = geomBuilder.New(salome.myStudy)

# need to retrieve all objects from that study -----------
go = salome.myStudy.FindObjectByPath("/Geometry")
it = salome.myStudy.NewChildIterator( go )
it.InitEx(True)
while it.More():
    so = it.Value()
    it.Next()
    go = so.GetObject()
    if go:
        #print(so.GetName())
        exec( "%s = go"%so.GetName() )
```

Comment: Is unclear your question (and ambiguos)

Comment: The question you linked to already explains why you should use a dictionary instead of separately-named variables.

Comment: When you find yourself trying to programmatically create individually-named variables, that is a strong indication that you are [doing something wrong](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BrenBarn I understand why I should use a dictionary (therefore, as shown in the code, I am using a dictionary).  My problem is calling up the different objects that were created previously in a Salome file (see edit).

Comment: How do you have access to the Salome file and get vars?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi See the updated edit.  My script is currently being loaded and ran in the Python console in Salome, although eventually I will look at how to run it without having to open the Salome GUI at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in method [globals()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#globals), which will return a dictionary of `{'object_name':object_value}`, this way:

```
default_value = 0
for i in range(1,4):
    Things['thing_%d'%i] = globals().get('object_%d' % i, default_value)
```

The `default_value` is there in case the variable does not exists which will return `default_value` instead of raising `KeyError` exception

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the values of those variables:

```
variables = (object_1, object_2, object_3)

Things = {}
for i, value in enumerate(variables):
    Things['thing_%d' % i] = value
```

At that point, you can also use a dictionary comprehension:

```
Things = { 'thing_%d' % i: value for i, value in enumerate(variables) }
```

But accessing the variables in a dynamic way, without specifying them first, is usually a bad idea and a sign for a bad design. You should change the way those variables are created in the first place then.

Comment: See my edit, but basically I cannot change the way the original variables are created without editing my Salome file.

Answer (score 1):

Following is one of the way to do what you want to do

```
object_1 = 7
object_2 = 8
object_3 = 51

Things = {}

for i in range(1,4):
    Things['thing_%d'%i] = globals()['object_%d'%i]
```

Comment: This does not do what you think it is doing.  It is creating new strings (called 'object_1', etc.) that are not related to the original variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary instead of the three different variables, with the key as `object_i` and the value as  its value. Example -

```
objects = {'object_1':7,
           'object_2':8,
           'object_3':51}
```

Then you can access the dictionary values just as you are going to create the keys for your `Things` list -

```
for i in range(1,4):
    Things['thing_%d'%i] = objects['object_%d'%i]
```

---

The above would be one of the better solutions, but if for reason you cannot use the dictionary, you can use `globals()` function which returns the global namespace (of global variables) as a dictionary and then you can access your variables using strings. Example -

```
object_1 = 7
object_2 = 8
object_3 = 51

# create new dictionary
Things = {}
gbl = globals()
# populate dictionary
for i in range(1,4):
    Things['thing_%d'%i] = gbl['object_%d'%i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try in this way:

```
>>> object_1 = 7  
>>> vars()['object_1']
7
```