# Need to get length of data frame stored in elements of list in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This problem can be solved by using different variable names in the loop. However, I need to check whether we can find the length of elements of List which can store data frames.

I have written code to read all .csv file stored in a folder. I have created the list containing the characters. Now, I am reading one by one csv files from a folder and storing as data frames in elements of list. Hence, all Elements of list contain data frame which is obtained by reading csv files. I.e., List element 0 - "a" contain one data frame, List element 1 - "b" contain other data frames and so on. I need to find the length of Data frames contained by elements of the list. I am using len(), but this reflects the only length of the list. Kindly suggest me some solution.

Below mentioned is the code.

```
url = "C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/SEdge/Proec/Day/Master Files/20-12-2017/"

count = 0;

lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

os.chdir(url)

for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):

    join = url + file;

    lst[count] = pd.read_csv(join)

    count +=1;
```

print(len(lst[1]))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create different variable names while in a loop? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop-python)

Comment: You are not suppose to store data in a string, they are called variables. Though there is a dtype called dictionary to do exactly what you want. A bit more understanding of data structrures is required  from your side.

Comment: I have no clue why you're filling a list with a, b, c, d and then subsequently replacing it with something else. Why not just create an empty list and then use `list.append`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ perhaps a misunderstanding of dictionary over a list.

Comment: @Dark I'm not so sure they even want a dictionary here because they're just inserting by index. It seems like they just want to put everything into a list and measure the length of each one. But this code really makes it hard to understand what they really want to do. Perhaps some input and expected output would help.

Comment: @COLDSPEED... I want to create different variables. For this, I was not aware of the dictionary, hence I use list element to store different data frames.

Comment: @Dark, in my code, elements of lists contain data frames, but is it possible to find the length of data frames??

Comment: @sonismit Why not find the length as you read it? `df = pd.read_csv(join); print(len(df)); di[lst[count]] = df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant store data in a string. You have to store them in a variable. Since you are looping over a bunch of csv file the opt data structure is dictionary. i.e

An improvement of your own code :

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d']
di = {} 

for count, file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")):
    join = url + file;
    di[lst[count]] = pd.read_csv(join)
```

`di['a']` stores the first csv file. Similarly `di['b]` the second one and so on.

Now if you do `len(di[lst[1]])` this will give you the length of the csv file 1.

For more details about datastructures I suggest you to go through [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Use `enumerate` so you don't need an external count variable.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ there are so many improvements that can be done here. I leave it to OP with this.

Comment: @Dark I am not clear about how to use enumerate. Can you provide me code line with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dark... Got it. Thanks. enumerate is useful when we need to increment counter itself. I will assign values to both count and files.

Comment: You got it. Happy coding. You will love python for this