# Python- iterating over multiple files to read into a data frame

Tags: python-3.x

### Here is the working code:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve 
import requests
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
```

### WORKING CODE

```
icd9_link = "https://www.cob.cms.hhs.gov/Section111/assets/section111/Section111ValidICD9-2017.xlsx"
icd9_map= pd.read_excel(icd9_link, sheet_name=0, header=0)
```

### NOT WORKING CODE

#### Define function which will name ICD_9_map_ and use correct link

```
fx =  icd"{0}"_map_= pd.read_excel(icd"{1}"_link,    sheet_name=0, header=0)
```

### #

```
y = [9,10]
  for x in y:
   fx.format(x, x)
```

Comment: You can't do what you are looking to do, you are probably looking for a `dict`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop

Comment: Thank you AChampion! you pointed me in the right direction.