# Python: naming variables by programming?

Tags: python

Is it possible to name the variables in Python by programs:

For instance, something like:

```
for i in range(3):
  var_%%i = i
```

And after the piece of code, we will have three variables: `var_0`, `var_1` and `var_2`.

Comment: Do *not* use dynamic variables. It is almost 100% certainly unneeded. Instead, use a *container*, like a list or a dict.

Comment: Yeah, my answer is there to answer your question, but (heh, never thought I would be saying this) please **don't** use it. You're better off using some sort of a container. See the marked duplicate question for more information.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to name the variables in Python by programs

Yes, but it is really, extremely bad practice.

> And after the piece of code, we will have three variables: var_0, var_1 and var_2.

If you really want to do this, you could use `exec` (note - REALLY bad idea, security issues and all that):

```
for i in range(3):
  exec("var_" + str(i) + " = i")
```

However, **DO NOT DO THIS. IT IS BAD PROGRAMMING PRACTICE**

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop) for a more practical solution involving dictionaries.

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6181959/9717184) about a second approach, and why it is VERY, very bad to use either of the approaches.

---

But seriously.

## Don't do it.

Comment: `exec` is really bad practice, it's not safe at all, just like `eval`

Comment: @U9-Forward I know that, I'm just answering OP's question. I never said it was recommended to do this.

Comment: @U9-Forward in this case, it is perfectly safe. However, this is still a terrible practice

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's right.

Comment: Understandable. I edited accordingly.