# How to create differently Label name?

Tags: python

I wanna create differently Label name in Tkinter. For example..

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.tk()
for i in range(1,10)
    "{}{}".format("Name", i) = tkinter.Label(root, text = i)
    "{}{}".format("Name", i).pack
```

I know "format" is not right instructions. But I already search many page to find solution...

Comment: Use a dictionary

Comment: From your question, one can only guess what you're asking. Please be discrete about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Is not clear at all.

Comment: [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html)

Comment: I am sorry guys. I already revision my question. hope that can let you to understand... I am sorry guys :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary for what you want:

```
d = {}
for i in range(1,10):
    d["{}{}".format('text', i)] = i

{'text1': 1,
 'text2': 2,
 'text3': 3,
 'text4': 4,
 'text5': 5,
 'text6': 6,
 'text7': 7,
 'text8': 8,
 'text9': 9}
```

Comment: I am sorry my friend. Is my question let you misunderstand. I'm sorry :( . But thank you for your help. :)