# How to add a series of dictionaries of random numbers to a single list

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a list that holds dictionaries of randomly generated colors. So for instance, the first dictionary of the list would be color 0 with values of 255, 255, 255. I am getting a syntax error with the "color{x}" where python is saying that it should be an integer or a splice, but not a string. Removing the color part gives me another error where python is saying the set object has no format attribute.

This is using pygame 1.9.4 and python 3.7 and I am rather new to python programming in general. I have tried messing with the "color{x}" part, but this previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop) had something similar that work for them, so I just copied the syntax to see if I could get it to work.

```
colors = []
colorLength = len(colors)
for x in range(3):
    colors["color{x}".format(x)]= random.randint(0,255), 
           random.randint(0,255), random.randint(0,255)
    #colors.append()
else:
    print(colorLength)
```

I am trying to get the list colors to hold 3 dictionaries (at the moment, plan on expanding the list when I get it working), that hold a randomly generated color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you actually want a dictionary of tuples. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = {i: tuple(np.random.randint(256, size=3)) for i in range(3)}

print(a)
{0: (65, 168, 140), 1: (193, 85, 66), 2: (28, 25, 7)}
```

Comment: I am always astonished what numpy is good for :) pulling it in for random numbers when nothing else uses numpy is a bit mucht though.

Comment: yeah, sorry eheh. Work with numpy everyday nowadays, so it is easy to fall in some overkills with it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `list` with `dictionary` - a list is simply that ... a list - an indexable collection  of things . What you need is a dictionary - something that stores a *value* under a *key* . Dictionarys are created by:  `colors = {}`.

The other error you get is from using str.format() with a named parameter -you can omit the x or fix it like this:

```
for xxx in range(3):
    # x is the name inside the {x} and it should be replaced by xxx
    colors["color{x}".format( x = xxx)] = ...
```

if you just use

```
for xxx in range(3):
    colors["color{}".format(xxx)] = ...
```

`format` will replace positionally .. the 1st `{}`placeholder is replaced with the `1st` value in `format( 1st, 2nd, ...)` etc.

Readup:

- [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)
- [more on lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)
- [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
- [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

---

Fixed code:

```
import random 

colors = {} # create empty dictionary

for x in range(3):
    # random.choices creates k random values from the given iterable in one go
    colors["color{}".format(x)] = random.choices(range(0,256), k =3) 

print(colors)
```

Output:

```
{'color0': [189, 5, 3], 'color1': [57, 218, 56], 'color2': [64, 150, 255]}
```

Doku:

- [random.choices(iterable, k= number)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)

---

If you *really* need tuples, you can use `tuple( random.choices(range(0,256), k =3) )`