# Creating variables (axes) in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to create a bunch of graphs based on a lot of previous code.  I cant "hardcode" the axes variables because the spacing would be all wrong.

I have an arbitrary amount of axes that each need formatting as part of the whole, so I cannot create them individually.

What I have so far:
I read [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop) , but as with half of all questions, it simply doesn't get answered, instead receiving some vaguely related code.

What I have:

```py
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((m, n), (j, k), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((m, n), (j+1, k+1), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((m, n), (j+2, k+2), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((m, n), (j+3, k+3), colspan=1, rowspan=1)

ax1.plot(df['colA'], df['colB'])
etc
```

What I think I need

```py
axcount = anyinteger
for i in np.arange(axcount):
  ax & str(i+1) = plt.subplot2grid((m, n), (j + (i+1 - 1), k + (i+1 - 1)), colspan=1, rowspan=1)

  ax & str(i+1) .plot(df['colA'], df['col' & chr(i+66)])
```

which is necessary because I will need to spec each axi's plot.

I am extremely new to this whole python thing, and from what Ive learned so far, it can do basically anything if you can find the syntax/function for it.  Im hoping someone has the syntax/function that would allow me to solve my problem.

Comment: `m`,`n`,`j` and `k` are undefined in your code. Maybe it would help to show the desired geometry of the axes that you want to create?

Comment: Are you trying to create a pair-wise scatter plot from a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @DizietAsahi  m,n,j,k are integers.  Doesnt matter what their value is (j and k will probably be 0).  It is determined from prev code.  For arguments sake, m=10, n=10, j = 0, k=0. but m and n could also be 12 and 123583

Comment: Your code only creates axes on the diagonal, is that what you are trying to do? Or are you trying to fill the grid with as many axes as required?

Comment: Im still trying to figure how exactly my bigger loops will look, but that is not my main issue.  That i havent define mnjk or that the loop itself only plots diags at the moment is secondary issues I have.  The primary issue still stands, regardless of the other "little things", is that " ax & str(i+1) = " is not valid syntax or logic for that matter

Comment: Suggest you just use plt.subplots outside your loop which will return an mxn array of axes handles that you can then access via axs[i, j].plot.   There is no need to “name” each axes separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to put each of the axes instances into a list, so that you can loop through the list and modify each axes properties that way?

```
fig = plt.figure()
m = 4
n = 4
ax_all = []
for j in range(m):
    for k in range(n):
        ax = plt.subplot2grid((m, n), (j, k), colspan=1, rowspan=1)
        ax_all.append(ax)

for ax in ax_all:
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
```

Comment: for arguments sake, I may have 3 axes, or 3000000.  I cant do it in a list if the list itself and the objects it contains isnt programatically created.

Comment: OK. I've edited the above so that it is fully programmatic, with the list of axes generated within the loop. You can change the `j` and `k` loops so that only the axes you want are created. You might also want to look at the `get_axes()` method of `Figure` instances, which returns a list of all axes in a figure.

Comment: Ill give it a go, it makes sense.  Will report back soon

Comment: Good stuff.  It works 100%.  There was no need for me to put them all into a list to call later, I simply specd the axes in the first loop.  Small adjustments were made to the loop to ensure the graphs ended up where they should on the grid.