# Problem with creating unique names in for-loop for multiple variables

Tags: python, for-loop, names

Basing on: [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop)

I created my `nameCreator()` function, that within call two other functions.
I would like to ask you, what may cause that it doesn't work as I want it.

after printing `nameDict` is see only `{}` as result. So as I suppose, the variables aren't even created.

```
def nameCreator(number):
    nameDict={}
    for x in range(number):
        nameDict["socketMC{0}".format(x)] = socket_creator(arg1, arg2, "analysedSocket{}".format(x))
        nameDict["threadMC{0}".format(x)] = threading.Thread(target=MC_analysis, args=(arg1, arg2, nameDict["socketMC{}".format(x)]))
    print(nameDict)
    return nameDict
```

I would expect from function to iterate `number` times, where in each iteration loop creates 2 objects and at the end return nameDict that can be used somewhere else.

**Example:**

```
socketMC0, threadMC0
socketMC1, threadMC1
```

where `socketMC{number}` is a sock object and `threadMC{number}` is a thread.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: how do you call the function?

Comment: I don't see why the code you pasted here should fail - are you sure that `number` was not 0 when you called your function? The approach, though, is a bit strange. Are you going to do that `format(...)` thing everytime you want to access something in your dict? It would be simpler to use the number as key, and a dict with socket and thread as value, or simply a list...

Comment: Actually you were right about calling function with argument `0`. I had in my program this object and variable: `MCAST_GROUP = [239.0.1.104]      number = len(MCAST_GROUP)-1`. I understood my mistake when I added another multicast group to my list, where after calling `nameCreator` it indeedly went once through iteration. I misunderstood fact that in the `for x in range(number):` im not providing index but number of how many `forloop` will be executed.
thanks for help :)