# How do I quickly append or concatenate many pandas dataframes from pkl files?

Tags: python, pandas

I have approx 50,000 `.pkl` files, which each contain two pandas, which I want to append to two large pandas.

I tried to loop over the files, reading them in, and appending one by one which gets painfully slow ([why? see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower)):

```
DF_a = pd.DataFrame
DF_b = pd.DataFrame

for appended_file in os.listdir(folderwithallfiles):
     with open(appenddirectory + appended_file, 'rb') as data:
        df_a, df_b = pickle.load(data)
     DF_a= pd.concat([DF_a, df_a], axis = 0]
     DF_b= pd.concat([DF_b, df_b], axis = 0)
```

As suggested in the linked post, I am trying to build a list of pandas to concatenate, but the only way I can think of doing it would be to rename the dataframes in the loop ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop)), which is advised against. I do not see how I can fit them in a dictionary and concat from there. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
DF_a = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(appenddirectory+filename)[0] for filename in appendedfiles])
DF_b = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(appenddirectory+filename)[1] for filename in appendedfiles])
```

since `pd.read_pickle` reads a list of pandas if multiple pandas are in the `pkl` file