# how to append more than one list of time series correlation in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, correlation

I want to take correlation between two time series. I used np.correcoef to get the correlations as list. Now I introduced lag suppose 3, how to save 3 different list for 3 different lags.

I tried

```
 for k in range(0,4,1):
      corr_k= [] 
      corr_k.append( np.corrcoef ( T[(365-k):(730-k)] ,T[365:730]) )
```

I want my result as corr_0 , corr_1, ... for respective lags 
But I am getting corr_k only. 
I need to make adjacency matrix after this step for each k value. I am using netCDF file as m data and T is temperature. 
Any idea how to do that?
thank you.

Comment: your are re-initializing `corr_k` at each iteration, hence you only get the last one at the end. Try to define `corr_k=[]` before the loop

Answer (score 0):

EDITED WITH MINIMUM EXAMPLE

```
import numpy as np
T = np.random.rand(100) #defines a dummy T with size 100
corr = {}
for k in range(4):
   corr[k] = np.corrcoef(T[50-k:100-k],T[50:100])
```

returns a dictionary `corr` containing arrays. For instance :

```
corr[0]
> array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
```

If this is not applicable to your case, maybe the issue is in the `corrcoef`, not the "appending" part!

---

EDITED WITH DICT

When you ask for `corr_k` in your loop, python has no way of knowing that you want `k` as a number. So it consider that your variable name is `corr_k` and not `corr_0` and so on as you would like. Which is hopeful, think about the nightmare it would be if python changed all `k` character on its own! So, to specify a variable name which changes with the loop index, use a dictionary (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop)) and store the lists in it:

```
corr = {}
 for k in range(4):
      corr[k] = np.corrcoef ( T[(365-k):(730-k)] ,T[365:730] )
```

Then you will have your outputs with: `corr[0]`, `corr[1]`, `corr[2]`, `corr[3]`.

---

It is difficult to test your code as we do not have `T` here, but as a first insight I see that for each step your are defining again `corr_k=[]`, hence overwriting your list rather than appending it. Try:

```
corr_k= [] 
for k in range(4):
      corr_k.append( np.corrcoef ( T[(365-k):(730-k)] ,T[365:730]) )
```

Comment: No .. it is not working. I got the total corr_k at the end of the loop, instead of corr_0, corr_1,... Actually I need to make adjacency matrix from list after this step. My data is actually netcdf files and T is temperature.

Comment: No  ... I am still not getting my desired result. I am getting corr_0 and so on as a single digit result,   but I am expecting a list instead. I explained my problem in details  here  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972598/how-to-convert-any-arbitrary-list-to-an-adjaceny-matrix-in-python]

Comment: @Ruby with the dictionary, your output is `corr[0]`, not `corr_0`. Please clarify for *this* question your input (with a minimal working example for T) and desired output, we cannot help you as it is

Comment: Sorry for typo mistake, I got corr[0] as a single digit. Here is the link for T   
[https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E-hGmdhCa7zQ3nx_u9hLNxdlE7WKr1de?usp=sharing]

Comment: I edit my code with a minimal working example, you should **not** give your real data here! For your future questions, please check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Ruby make sure that you are calculating what you think with your `corrcoef` : print your `T[(365-k):(730-k)]` for instance to know what you are asking