# How to create n matrices with the same shape

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am doing a homework, where I need 20 matrices with shape (m,n), with names `a_0`, `a_1`, `a_2`, ..., `a_19`. At first they all can be filled with zeros. How can I do it using for?
Working on `Python`

I can create them all by myself like:

```py
a_0 = np.zeros((m,n))
```

...

```py
a_19 = np.zeros((m,n))
```

but what if I need 1000 matrices?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop)

Comment: It seems to me that it is easier to use a 3D-array instead of manually (or via for-loop) creating 20 2D arrays. Is it really impossible to use `a = np.zeros((10,m,n))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where lists could come in handy, as you do not require a particular name for each of your variables, just a way of accessing them. For a list you access the items by the index(number) in which they are ordered, starting from 0.

eg. you could write:

```
a = []
for i in range(1000):
    a.append(np.zeros((m,n))
```

Then you can later access them using their index in the list, e.g. `a[0]` for the first matrix, and `a[241]` for matrix number 242.

Alternatively you could just make a numpy array with an even higher dimension:

```
a = np.zeros((1000,m,n))
```

In the same way, `a[0]` would then be the first matrix.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question correctly as matrices are not named `with names a_0, a_1, a_2, ...,` as it is written in the question. Check my answer.

Comment: @RomanOrac True, but it addresses the problem to be solved. It is seldom meaningful to have a dict representing what really should be a list, but with cumbersome notation. Likewise, I don't think we should advocate `exec` to new Python users. I believe this is a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and have answered accordingly

Comment: I agree with @M.T that this is clearly a case of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Yes, we should attempt to answer questions as best we can, but sometimes that isn’t the right thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

You are currently using numpy arrays (numpy also has a matrix type), so I assume you need arrays.

To create an arbitrary number of arrays that can be retrieved with a name, I would use a python dictionary.

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000
m = 10
n = 10

arrays = {'a_%d' % i: np.zeros((m, n)) for i in range(N)}
```

Comment: Why not use f-strings instead of the old `%`?

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
N = 10
m, n = 10, 20
for i in range(N):
     exec( "a_%d = np.zeros((%d,%d))" % (i,m,n) )
```