# creating dynamic nested xml from Excel

Tags: python, excel, xml

I'm trying to convert Excel to nested XML and could not succeed as expected.

Here is my code.

```
import openpyxl
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

# reading data from the source, xls
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='C:\GSH\parent_child.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
row_max = ws1.max_row

# creating xml tree structure
root = etree.Element('Hierarchy')

# iterating through the xls and creating children based on the condition
for row_values in range(2, row_max+1):
    parent = etree.SubElement(root, 'parent')
    parent.text = ws1.cell(column=1, row=row_values).value
    root.append(parent)
    if (ws1.cell(column=1, row = row_values).value == ws1.cell(column=2, row = row_values-1).value):
        print("------Inside if condition")
        print(ws1.cell(column=2, row=row_values).value)
        child = etree.SubElement(parent, 'child')
        child.text = ws1.cell(column=2, row=row_values).value
        parent.append(child)
        print("-------Inside if condition")
    tree = etree.ElementTree(root)

tree.write('C:\GSH\gsh.xml')
```

I am getting XML like this..

[image]

However, my XML should look like this.

[image]

Any suggestions, please.

[image]

The above is the source XLS from which I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

You can set variable name instead of parent and child. This code is only part of your list and seems tricky but works fine. `d[child[i]].text = " "` is only to show both sides of tags. For making var in loop with dictionary, please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

India = ET.Element('India')  # set root
parent = ['India', 'Telangana', 'Telangana', 'Telangana','Nalgonda']  # parent list
child = ['Telangana', 'Cyberabad', 'Warangal','Nalgonda','BusStation']  # child list

d = {}  # use dictionary to define var in loop
d['India'] = India

for i in range(len(child)):

    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == parent[i]:
            pa = v
            break

    d[child[i]] = ET.SubElement(pa, child[i])
    d[child[i]].text = " "  # to get both side of tags

tree = ET.ElementTree(India)
tree.write('gsh.xml')

# <India>
# <Telangana>
# <Cyberabad> </Cyberabad>
# <Warangal> </Warangal>
# <Nalgonda>
# <BusStation> </BusStation>
# </Nalgonda>
# </Telangana>
# </India>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, you saved my day..Can we get the values outside the tags, instead of them inside? I mean instead of </Nellore><Chittoor> </Chittoor><Vijayawada>, I am still struggling to get <parent>Nellore</Parent><Child>Chittoor</Chittoor>

Comment: I have updated the xls source in original question.

Comment: I don’t see what is your final results. In my example code, varname is str(varname). Use .text to put string inside a tag. Please try.

Comment: I have updated the answer on final results which should look like. I'm trying your suggestion and keep you posted..

Comment: I think you’ve far changed both question and expected answer. Still, you can do by expandibng my code. I’m afraid I won’t do anymore.

Comment: yeah, you are right. Thanks for the answer man. I will try doing something from here.