# Iterating through a dictionary and assigning values to a variable

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic-programming, pyspark

I have a dictionary "d" which has a 10 keys with  pyspark dataframes as values.

```
 >> d.keys()
  dict_keys (['Py1', 'Py2', 'Py3', 'Py4', 'Py7', 'Py8', 'Py15', 'Py20', 'Py21', 'Py22']
```

I am currently taking each key and its value, then assigning it to a variable like so:

```
   df1 = d['Py1'] 
   df2 = d['Py2']
   df3 = d['Py3']
  .
  .
  .
  df10 = d['Py22']
```

I then do various manipulations using pyspark. What is the best way achieving this without the redundancy? here is what i attempted..

```
 newname = "df"
 counter = 1
 for key in df_list.keys():
 key = newname + str(counter)
 counter+=1
 print (key)
```

But when i do print(df1) i get a "name 'df1' is not defined" error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be df1 = d['Py1']?

Comment: @HarshithBolar correct, error on the question. I'm not assigning values that way in my actual script.

Comment: Why do you *want* individual variables, instead of just using the values in the `dict` directly? A bunch of sequentially named variables is [almost always the wrong thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6181935/364696)...

Comment: @ShadowRanger I want to work on the dataframes individually and its easier for me to access them and do data manipulations this way.

Comment: @user12501784: It really, really isn't though. `d['Py1']` is not meaningfully more difficult than `df1`, while making sure the latter (and its 22-odd siblings) even exist is a royal pain. If you think this is a problem you need solved, you probably have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) provided you have all the `df`s globally.

```
newname = "df"
d = {k: globals()[newname + str(counter)] for counter, k in enumerate(d, start = 1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have your `df` in a list called `dfs`.  I would use a combination of a comprehension and the `enumerate` function.

```
out = {newname + str(i): df for i, df in enumerate(dfs, 1)}
```

The function `enumerate` wraps an iterable and returns the tuple `(index, value)`.  It is very convenient when you need to refer to both the value and location of each element in a list.  Also note the use of tuple unpacking to give a name to both of the items returned by `enumerate`.