# Trial For Dynamic Python Variable Creation Without Using Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, error-handling

I was trying to create dynamically variables in python by the following code:

```
for i in range (1,10):
    xi = 'wow'
```

Surprisingly this didn't show any error, which I did expect. But on calling the variable, I experienced something unexpected:

```
>>>x1
NameError: name 'x1' is not defined
```

What supressed the error in the creation and what raised the error here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by **Dynamic Python Variable**?

```
for i in range (1,10):
    xi = 'wow'
```

This code basically assigning one variable `xi` to a string `'wow'` 9 times.

And you haven't defined `x1` anywhere (Python will not change `xi` into `x1` or `x2` they are all different variable name)

Comment: dymanic variable creation refers to creation of variable by  the code itself

Answer (score 2):

See Yosua's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61043943/7547749).

Please check out this question too: [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6181935/7547749)

If you really need to do it without a dictionary, you can use [Collin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47146969/7547749):

```
for i in range (1,10):
    exec(f"x{i} = 'wow'")
```

However, I would not recommend using this. It is not a very elegant solution.