# python: declear name in sequence in loop

Tags: python, string

I want to declare variable name in sequence:
Something like x_1, x_2, x_3,......., x_5 and assign value with them in python.
Something like x_i = i^2.

```
n = 10
for i in range(1, n):
    x_i = i**2

print(x_2)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: you could use `globals()` but i would not recommend it. just use a dict

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop)

Comment: It is not best practice to name variables sequences in a numbered way. Use a list instead.

Comment: Use a list: `x=[]`, `for i in range(n):`, `x.append(i**2)`, `print(x[2])`. And learn about list comprehensions too, `x=[i**2 for i in range(n)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this but its not recommended:

```
n = 10
for i in range(1, n):
    globals()[f'x_{i}'] = i**2

print(x_2) #4
```