# Create classes in loop

Tags: python

I want to create classes in a loop. I've found this question: [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop). But I want to associate a variable to a class, I can't use a list for that or a dictionary. How would I do so?

```
class Enemy():
    def __init__(self, type_):
        if type_ == 'demon':
            self.hp = random.randint(90, 110)
            self.dmg = [20, 40]
            self.dodge = 4
            loot_chance = random.randint(0, 10)
            if loot_chance <= 8:
                self.loot = loot(['hp', 'dmg'])
            if loot_chance == 9:
                self.loot = loot(['hp'])
            else:
                self.loot = loot(['dmg'])
```

I want to do this more efficiently:

```
enemy0 = Enemy('demon')
enemy1 = Enemy('demon')
enemy2 = Enemy('demon')
enemy3 = Enemy('demon')
enemy4 = Enemy('demon')
...
```

Comment: Why you can't use `list`? Seems like an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I can? I don't understand how. A list is like a variable that stores more than 1 data. I want a lot of variables. That is my logic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) tl;dr use a list

Comment: How on earth could enemy0, enemy1, enemy2... be a better solution than enemy[0], enemy[1], enemy[2]...?

Comment: enemies = [Enemy('demon') for x in range(10)]

Comment: Oh wait, do you not know how to use a list? If so, I'll write you an answer.

Comment: I thought I did? I'm pretty sure I do

Comment: RefusVS, please explain further, you are using indices to access parts of the list right?

Comment: Yes, he is using indices to access the elements of a list.

Comment: Maybe you want a set, not a list.

Comment: I think that would do, I'm going to comeback if this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes this works, thank you. I had the mind set that I need to make variables for every data for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using individual variables you should use a [list](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)

You could then append your data into the list and access it using
`list[0]` where 0 is the item you wish to retrieve.