# Python3 - Create variables with 'i' value at the end of variables' name

Tags: python-3.x

How do I create a loop in which I will create variables with name having the 'i' value at the end of variable's name?
So far I have this but it is not working:

```
for i in range(0,4):
#v{i} should be v1, v2, v3, v4 at the end of loop with values being the 'i' value respectively
v{i} = i
i+=1
```

Thank you

Comment: Change `v{i} = i` to `v["name-" + str(i)]  = i`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0,4):
    vars()['v' + str(i)] = i
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you don't want to do this in such way. If you would want to retrieve a value given a certain "variable" name, I would create a proper Python data structure for it, such as a `dictionary`:

```
d = {}
for i in range(0,4):
    d[f"name{i}"] = i
    i+=1
```

Look at this thread for further explanation and insights why you want to follow this strategy:

[How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop)

There you will also find an actual answer on how to *technically* do what you want in Python, but is discouraged.