# creating multiple instances of a class in Python

Tags: python, instance

so let's say there is a class A

and I can create instances of class A as follow

```
inst1 = A()

inst2 = A()

inst3 = A()
...
```

Can I do this job more neatly?

I have to create the instances as many as a certain number that is given by a server (the number can vary every time).

I'm expecting to do something like

```
for NUM in range(2):
    inst + NUM = A()
```

then the instances I want to get as a result would be three instances (inst0, inst1, inst2) that are class A.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe use a list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop)

Comment: Don't dynamically create variables use a *container* like a list or a dict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't create single variable if you don't assign them a specified name, for creating unknow amount of variables use lists (inndexed) or dictionarys (named):

**Lists**

with for loops:

```
instances = []

for x in range('number of instances'):

    instances.append(A())
```

with list comprehension (recommended):

```
instances = [A() for x in range('number of instances')]
```

**Dictionarys**

with for loops:

```
instances = {}

for x in range('number of instances'):

    instances['inst' + str(x)] = A()
```

with dict comprehension (recommended):

```
instances = {'inst' + str(x): A() for x in range('number of instances')}
```

Answer (score 3):

use a dictionary or list to create your variable

dictionary

```
d={}
for x in range(1, 10):
    d[f"inst{x}"] = A()
```

list

```
inst=[]
for i in range(10):
    inst.append(A())
```