# Creating and Assigning values to a variable within a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, for-loop, variables

I want to create variables names to be assigned to each index in the `values` list. So `Result0 = 10, Result1 = 3, Result2 = 44, Result1 = 56601`. Trying to code a function that creates and assigns variables depending on the length of the `values` list. The Code below does not work.

Code:

```
values = [10,3,44,56601]
k= 0
for n in values:
    Result{k} = n
    k+=1
```

Expected Result

```
Result0 = 10
Result1 = 3
Result2 = 44
Result3 = 56601
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this approach? Try using `dict`

Comment: First you rather use a  `dictionaly`  instead of assigning everything to the global

Comment: Possible answer for a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop

Comment: Don't dynamically create variables. You already have a list. *Use the list*

Answer (score 0):

As earlier posts, and @hulkinBrian pointed out similar case, this will be the approach: (credit to them all!)

```
dc = {}
for x in [10, 3, 44, 56601]:
    dc['Result{0}'.format(x)] = x
```