# Is there a way to create new variables that work inside a method?

Tags: python

I want to define new variables within a class method, but it just shows `AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'var1'`:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.stuff = stuff
    
        for i in range(len(self.stuff)):
            locals()['var' + str(i)] = "e"
        
d = MyClass("hello")
print(d.var1)
```

And if I write it this way, it'll say `name 'self' is not defined` instead:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.stuff = stuff
    
    for i in range(len(self.stuff)):
        locals()['var' + str(i)] = "e"
        
d = MyClass("hello")
print(d.var1)
```

I know `locals()['var' + str(i)] = "e"` will work like this if I just use it outside a method, but I want my class to recieve data from the outside.

```
class MyClass():    
    for i in range(len("hello")):
        locals()['var' + str(i)] = "e"
        
d = MyClass()
print(d.var1)
```

Comment: Why not use list? Declaring variables like this is very bad method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [setattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr). Looks like you want to set custom attributes on your class instance. Why you might want to do that is a different topic.

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.stuff = stuff

        for i, letter in enumerate(self.stuff):
            setattr(self, f"var{i}", letter)


d = MyClass("hello")
print(d.var0)
# Will print "h".
print(d.var1)
# Will print "e".
print(d.var2)
# Will print "l".
# etc.
```