# Saving the output of a for loop in a labeled list in Python

Tags: python, list

Consider the following loop:

```
import random
 
for m in range(0,2):
    rand_list=[]
    n=10
    for i in range(n):
        rand_list.append(random.randint(3,9))
    print(rand_list)
```

That outputs two lists as:

```
[6, 9, 8, 7, 4, 8, 8, 4, 9, 9]
[9, 5, 3, 8, 3, 4, 8, 9, 3, 3]
```

How can I possibly label them with the dummy variable `m` define in the loop, for example `lst[0],lst[1]` or such, in order to compose the mean result

```
lst_mean = lst[0]+lst[1]/2
```

or similar quantities?

Note I know that the indexing here is not correct. The idea is that in the end of the loop for each `m` I define a list labeled by `m` and contains the corresponding result of `rand_list`.

Comment: please elaborate problem

Comment: I just want to save each list the loop spits out.

Comment: Add them to an outer list, just like you add random numbers to each of them.

Comment: @Marion Then simply define 2 empty lists before the inner loop?

Comment: Well, if i have 100 lists I would not like to define each one individually.

Comment: I am not asking to join/append the result of each resulting list. I want to save them individually by running the loop once.

Comment: You can assign variable names dynamically...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6181959/14196135

Comment: @Marion what do you mean by "save"? Assign to a new variable? So you want 100 variables with 100 different names?

Comment: You can use a dictionary where you can label the each random list produced in each loop with the `m` that is the iteration variable. Say `d={}`. then `d[m]=rand_list`

Comment: Using globals dynamic variables is a solution to this problem but is a bad practice. A dictionary like Debi suggested is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

You need a list of lists.

```
import random

lst = []
for m in range(2):
    rand_list = []
    n = 10
    for i in range(n):
        rand_list.append(random.randint(3, 9))
    lst.append(rand_list)

print(lst)
```

Example output:

```
[[5, 7, 9, 7, 8, 9, 9, 5, 3, 9], [8, 8, 5, 7, 7, 9, 8, 7, 4, 7]]
```

Now you can calculate the mean result.

```
result = [sum(values) / len(values) for values in zip(*lst)]
print(result)
```

Output

```
[6.5, 7.5, 7.0, 7.0, 7.5, 9.0, 8.5, 6.0, 3.5, 8.0]
```

If you want more lists you can change the `2` in `for m in range(2):` to a different number.

Comment: I think what OP wants is dynamic variable assignment. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6181959/14196135 Judging from the comments.

Comment: Maybe. But that's a really, really, really bad idea. No sane programmer would use this if it's not for some kind of weird meta-programming. That's the reasons why other datastructures like a list exist.

Comment: Or in this case a dictionary does exactly whats needed in a very good way.

Comment: As a mathematician I indeed would think I need a dynamic variable but I think that @Matthias answer is something I can work with.

Comment: @Marion Then dynamic variables and dictionaries and a list of lists works. Take your pick

Comment: @Marion then why not use a NxM matrix with numpy? You preallocate the matrix full of zeros, at each iteration you fill one row `mat[row,:] = list` and then you can use `numpy.mean()` to calculate the mean, with the extra that you can select which axis to perform the reduction.