# Update a variable in a for loop?

Tags: python

I have a series of data and would like to perform the following opperation:

```
AA = [2, 4, 6, 8]
a = []
a = AA[0]

b = AA[1]
sum_1 = a+b 

c = AA[2]
sum_2 = sum_1 + c

d = AA[3]
sum_3 = sum_2 + d
```

To make it more concise, I'd like to put it in a `for loop`, but I can't figure out how.

The desired output for me will be the updated `sum_3`

Comment: append new values to list `a`.  Don't try to define new variables.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with numpy or xarray? If so, please edit your example to include real code, not pseudo code. If not, please remove these tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will do it for you:

```
AA = [2, 4, 6, 8]
s = 0
for a in AA:
    s += a
print(s)
```

```
20
```

Cheers

Comment: Why not `s = sum(AA)`?

Comment: He wanted something which uses a loop, but off course your approach works too