# Dynamically creating variables with a for loop and adding them to a list in python

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I want to use a for loop to dynamically name variables, assign the variables a value, and then add the variables to a list.

This is Tadeck's answer on how to dynamically create variables in a for loop from [How do you create different variable names while in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181935/how-do-you-create-different-variable-names-while-in-a-loop):

```
for x in range(0, 9):
    globals()['string%s' % x] = 'Hello'

print(string3) 

# Output: 'Hello'
```

Since I also want to  add the variables to a list, I tried:

```
lst = []
for x in range(0, 9):
lst.append(globals()['string%s' % x] = 'Hello')

print(lst)

# Output: SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="? 

# DESIRED OUTPUT: [string0, string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6, string7, string8]
```

I understand what the error message says, but I don't know how to get around it and get the desired output.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't. Use dictionaries.

Comment: @Jackster Have you noticed Tadeck's answer starts with "It is really bad idea, but..."?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`globals()` returns you a dict which contains all the variables, defined in current namespace ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)).

To understand better, you can modify the code as follows:

```
namespace_variables_dict = globals()

for x in range(0, 9):
    variable_name = 'string%s' % x
    namespace_variables_dict[variable_name] = 'Hello'

print(string3)
```

And add the names of new variables to the list:

```
lst = []
namespace_variables_dict = globals()
for x in range(0, 9):
    variable_name = 'string%s' % x
    namespace_variables_dict[variable_name] = 'Hello'
    lst.append(variable_name)

print(lst) # ['string0', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6', 'string7', 'string8']
```

Comment: But I have absolutely no idea why you need it..

Comment: I just want to know, it's how I learn. Thanks!